# Diff between two dates (datetime) in minutes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to check difference between two dates - from db and actual, but in minutes in JS/jQuery (I need to run function to check by ajax).
This is format of my date:

```
19-01-2016 22:18
```

I need something like this:

```
if ( (date_actual - date_db) < 1 minute ) {
   //do something
}
```

How can I do this?

**EDIT**: I created something like this, but I always getting same log, it's not change - http://jsbin.com/xinaki/edit?js,console

**EDIT 2**: Here it's working code, **BUT** now it's checking in the same hour/minute, ex. 12:50:50 and 12:50:58 show log only for this 2 seconds, but I need to 'stay' log on 1 minute
http://jsbin.com/laruro/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all dates are in the same format, and that they are strings, you could use this helper function to convert one or both of the strings to a real `Date()` object:

```
var makeDate = function(dateString) {
  var d = dateString.split(/[\s:-]+/);
  return new Date(d[2],d[1] - 1,d[0],d[3],d[4]);
}
```

And then use it like so to compare **a string to the current date**:

```
var diffInMin = function(dateString) {
  return ( new Date() /* < current date */ - makeDate(dateString) ) / ( 1000 * 60 );
};
```

or like this to compare **two date strings**:

```
var diffInMin = function(dateString1, dateString2) {
  // this assumes date string one will always be more recent than DateString2
  return ( makeDate(dateString1) - makeDate(dateString2) ) / ( 1000 * 60 ); 
};
```

Comment: what if the dates are `19-01-2016 22:18` and `19-01-2017 22:18` your diff will be `0`

Comment: @avrahamcool thanks for catching that, I think this new solution should work

Comment: @avrahamcool It's good! But ... I need to check 1 min. between two dates. Now it's checking in the same time, ex. 12:50:50 and 12:50:58 show log only for this 2 seconds, but I need to 'stay' log on 1 minute

Comment: @Vertisan not sure this is what you mean but if you want it to only log every minute then you can change the delay on the `setInterval` function from 1000 to 60000

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function diffInMin(dateString1, dateString2){
  return (+ new Date(dateString2) - new Date(dateString1))/(1000*60)
}
```

Comment: I do something like this, but always I getting FALSE - http://jsbin.com/xinaki/edit?js,console

Comment: Sorry, there was mistake two times was used dateString2 in function.

Comment: This unfortunately won't work because the dates are not in the proper format for the `Date()` object.

Comment: Any way you should be able to parse string that you have and create Date object. After that you will be able to use time difference.